# C++ small vs all caps datatype

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, typedef

Why in C++ (MSVS), datatypes with all caps are defined (and most of them are same)?

1. These are exactly the same. Why all caps versions are defined?

   `double` and `typedef double DOUBLE`

   `char` and `typedef char CHAR`
2. `bool` and `BOOL` (`typedef int BOOL`), here both all small and all caps represent Boolean states, why `int` is used in the latter?

What extra ability was gained through such additional datatypes?

Comment: Extra headache rather than extra ability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ALLCAPS typedefs started in the very first days of Windows programming (1.0 and before). Back then, for example, there was no such thing as a `bool` type. The Windows APIs and headers were defined for old-school C. C++ didn't even exist back when they were being developed.

So to help document the APIs better, compiler macros like `BOOL` were introduced. Even though `BOOL` and `INT` were both macros for the same underlying type (`int`), this let you look at a function's type signature to see whether an argument or return value was intended as a boolean value (defined as "0 for false, any nonzero value for true") or an arbitrary integer.

As another example, consider `LPCSTR`. In 16-bit Windows, there were two kinds of pointers: `near` pointers were 16-bit pointers, and `far` pointers used both a 16-bit "segment" value and a 16-bit offset into that segment. The actual memory address was calculated in the hardware as `( segment << 4 ) + offset`.

There were macros or typedefs for each of these kinds of pointers. `NPSTR` was a `near` pointer to a character string, and `LPSTR` was a `far` pointer to a character string. If it was a `const` string, then a `C` would get added in: `NPCSTR` or `LPCSTR`.

You could compile your code in either "small" model (using `near` pointers by default) or "large" model (using `far` pointers by default). The various `NPxxx` and `LPxxx` "types" would explicitly specify the pointer size, but you could also omit the `L` or `N` and just use `PSTR` or `PCSTR` to declare a writable or const pointer that matched your current compilation mode.

Most Windows API functions used `far` pointers, so you would generally see `LPxxx` pointers there.

`BOOL` vs. `INT` was not the only case where two names were synonyms for the same underlying type. Consider a case where you had a pointer to a *single character*, not a zero-terminated string of characters. There was a name for that too. You would use `PCH` for a pointer to a character to distinguish it from `PSTR` which pointed to a zero-terminated string.

Even though the underlying pointer type was exactly the same, this helped document the intent of your code. Of course there were all the same variations: `PCCH` for a pointer to a constant character, `NPCH` and `LPCH` for the explicit near and far, and of course `NPCCH` and `LPCCH` for near and far pointers to a constant character. Yes, the use of `C` in these names to represent *both* "const" and "char" was confusing!

When Windows moved to 32 bits with a "flat" memory model, there were no more `near` or `far` pointers, just flat 32-bit pointers for everything. But all of these type names were preserved to make it possible for old code to continue compiling, they were just all collapsed into one. So `NPSTR`, `LPSTR`, plain `PSTR`, and all the other variations mentioned above became synonyms for the same pointer type (with or without a `const` modifier).

Unicode came along around that same time, and most unfortunately, UTF-8 had not been invented yet. So Unicode support in Windows took the form of 8-bit characters for ANSI and 16-bit characters (UCS-2, later UTF-16) for Unicode. Yes, at that time, people thought 16-bit characters ought to be enough for anyone. How could there possibly be more than 65,536 different characters in the world?! (Famous last words...)

You can guess what happened here. Windows applications could be compiled in either ANSI or Unicode ("Wide character") mode, meaning that their default character pointers would be either 8-bit or 16-bit. You could use all of the type names above and they would match the mode your app was compiled in. Almost all Windows APIs that took string or character pointers came in both ANSI and Unicode versions, with an `A` or `W` suffix on the actual function name. For example, `SetWindowText( HWND hwnd, LPCSTR lpString)` became two functions: `SetWindowTextA( HWND hwnd, LPCSTR lpString )` or `SetWindowTextW( HWND hwnd, LPCWSTR lpString )`. And `SetWindowText` itself became a macro defined as one or the other of those depending on whether you compiled for ANSI or Unicode.

Back then, you might have actually wanted to write your code so that it could be compiled either in ANSI or Unicode mode. So in addition to the macro-ized function name, there was also the question of whether to use `"Howdy"` or `L"Howdy"` for your window title. The `TEXT()` macro (more commonly known as `_T()` today) fixed this. You could write:

```
SetWindowText( hwnd, TEXT("Howdy") );
```

and it would compile to either of these depending on your compilation mode:

```
SetWindowTextA( hwnd, "Howdy" );

SetWindowTextW( hwnd, L"Howdy" );
```

Of course, most of this is moot today. Nearly everyone compiles their Windows apps in Unicode mode. That is the native mode on all modern versions of Windows, and the `...A` versions of the API functions are shims/wrappers around the native Unicode `...W` versions. By compiling for Unicode you avoid going through all those shim calls. But you still can compile your app in ANSI (or "multi-byte character set") mode if you want, so all of these macros still exist.

Comment: I remember those days: the alpha version in a green binder with the three 5 and1/4 inch floppies and the mouse with green buttons and a shiny steel ball... I suspect the ultimate origin is a combination of the convention for C macros to be upper case, especially for constants such as TRUE and FALSE and a long habit of all caps assembly language practice, where case was mostly ignored anyway.

Comment: IIRC, at least Windows 3.x, which was a 16-bit system, ran in protected mode. This means, the segment address wasn't calculated as segment << 4, but rather by using the segment base address in the segment descriptor indicated by the segment register.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft decided to create macros or type aliases for all of these types, in the Windows code. It's possible that they were going for "consistency" with the all-caps WinAPI type aliases, like `LPCSTR`.

But what real benefit does it serve? None.

The case of `BOOL` is particularly headache-inducing. Although some old-school C had a convention of doing this (before actual `bool` entered the language), nowadays it really just confuses… especially when using WinAPI with C++.

Comment: Do you know for sure? Reference? I would suspect it's about their internal code styling as well...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I know for sure that it's silly and that I wish they hadn't done it. As for actual references you'll probably have to wait for an employee to come along.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I can't totally argue with that, but there's objectivity in here too: OP asks what ability was added, and as far as I'm aware the answer is factually "none".

Comment: I was wondering whether this might have been some misguided attempt at future-proofing, but couldn't really find a way to make that work logically.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can use me for a reference. :-) I was actively programming Windows in the days of 1.0. LRiO's answer is correct, and I posted a couple of other thoughts in my own answer. Feel free to ask any questions about this odd bit of history.

Answer (score 3):

This convention goes back more than 30 years to the early days of the Windows operating system.

Current practice in the '70s and early '80s was still to use all caps for programming in various assembly languages and the higher languages of the day, Fortran, Cobol... as well as command line interpreters and file system defaults. A habit probably rooted in the encoding of punch cards that goes back way further, to the dawn of the 20th century.

When I started programming in 1975, the card punch we used did not even support lowercase letters [as you can see on the pictures, it did not even have a shift key](http://www.feb-patrimoine.com/projet/serie_150/pelerod.htm).

[image]

MS/DOS was written in assembly language, as were most successful PC packages of the early '80s such as Lotus 1-2-3, MS Word, etc. C was invented at Bell Labs for the Unix system and took a long time to gain momentum in the PC world.

In the budding microprocessor world, there were literally 2 separate schools: the Intel little endian world with all caps assembly documentation and the big endian Motorola alternative, with small caps assembly, C and Unix operating systems and clones and other weird languages such as lisp.

Windows is the brainchild of the former and this proliferation of all caps types and modifiers did not seem ugly then, it looked consistent and reassuring. Microsoft tried various alternatives for the pointer modifiers: `far`, `_far`, `__far`, `FAR` and finally got rid of these completely but kept the original allcaps typedefs for compatibility purposes, leading to silly compromises such as 32-bit `LONG` even on 64-bit systems.

This answer is not unbiassed, but it was fun reviving these memories.

Answer (score 1):

Only MS knows.

The only benefit I can think of is for some types (e.g. `int`) whose size is OS dependant (see [the table here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)). This would allow to use 16 bits type on a 64 bits OS, with some more `typedefs` or `#defines`. The code would be easier to port to other OS versions.

Now, if this "portable" thing was true, then the rest of types would follow the same convention, even their sizes were the same in all machines.

Comment: But the code is literally for a specific OS. This kind of thing makes it harder, not easier, to port.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was designed to be easier to port to different CPU architectures within the same OS.

Comment: @immibis: That makes more sense, sort of. So on a different architecture the definition of `INT` would change from `int` to, what, one of the fixed-width types? To make it what it was on the reference architecture? But then why not just use the fixed-width type in the first place? Or at least make `INT` resolve to that

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fixed width types hadn't been invented yet. I'm not sure if C was standardized yet. `BYTE`, `WORD`, `DWORD`, (later `QWORD`) ***are*** the Windows fixed-width types. Not sure what the reason for making `INT` uppercase was - but probably just consistency. Some compilers didn't have `void` yet so they would've used `typedef int VOID;` on those compilers. Maybe there was one that had an unusual `int`, where `INT` had to not be `int`. (e.g. perhaps it had `int` as unsigned by default so they used `typedef signed int INT;`?)

Comment: @immibis: Ok, that makes some sense.